# Varnish Port Settings

Tags: nginx, centos, varnish

I'm stuck at some point in the installation of Varnish.  This is how it looked like before the Varnish:  Nginx Reverse Proxy + Apache + Centos 6 64 Bit

I installed the Varnish and set the ports as following. First of all we want to remove Nginx Reverse Proxy and switch to Apache completely. Because Varnish is not working properly at the moment.

**DEFAULT.VCL**

```
backend default {

.host = "127.0.0.1";

.port = "8080";

.first_byte_timeout = 60s;

.connect_timeout = 300s;
}
```

**VARNISH**

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \

-T localhost:6082 \

-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \

-u varnish -g varnish \

-S /etc/varnish/secret \

-s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,256m"
```

**httpd.conf**

```
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8080
```

**nginx-vhosts.conf**

```
  server {
        listen       176.xx.xx.xx:80;
        listen       127.0.0.1:80;
        #listen       [::1]:80;
        server_name  $hostname 176.xx.xx.xx;

        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/nginx-userdir.conf;

        location / {
                access_log off;
                proxy_pass http://176.xx.xx.xx:8080;
                proxy_set_header X-Client-IP      $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /nginx_static_files;
                proxy_set_header Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

I used the **curl -l** command for localhost and domain.com. How should i set the ports and IPs in order to make Varnish work properly?

**Localhost**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# curl -I http://localhost
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 11:35:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1
Link: <http://******.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 12:35:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish: 2
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Cache: MISS
Connection: keep-alive
```

**my domain.com**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# curl -I http://my domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 11:36:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 344285
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 11:30:57 GMT
ETag: "540dd-53796d5f31b86"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 12:30:57 GMT
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1
Pragma: public
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide information on how you expect traffic to flow through the various server processes. Also, in this case is Apache even in use? If not, remove it from the question, as it's just noise.

Comment: Actually we want to remove Nginx completely then use Apache + Varnish instead of it. I guess Nginx Reverse Proxy makes the problem right?,-

Comment: As I mentioned, please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added what we wanted to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem? All seems correct. Remove Nginx.
Then restart Apache and then restart Varnish.

Comment: Varnish seems in a passive state. http://imgur.com/OlnV2UO
I guess Nginx creates a problem here.

Comment: It is obvious from your curl results that you have Varnish and Nginx listening on same port 80 but different interfaces. You said yourself you don't need Nginx. So do yourself a favor and remove it then restart the services to make sure Varnish listens on external interface :)

Comment: HTTPD error: http://imgur.com/yk0hyzb :/ 
What's the problem?

Comment: Make sure you removed Nginx: ```sudo apt-get remove nginx``` (Ubuntu) or ```yum remove nginx``` (CentOS / Redhat) .  Remove any ```Listen 1.2.3.4:80``` or ```Listen 80``` directive in Apache. Restart Apache and Varnish.

Comment: Yes, Nginx has been removed. Now;

backend default {
  .host = "MY SERVER IP";
  .port = "8080";
  .first_byte_timeout = 60s;
  .connect_timeout = 300s;

VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80

Httpd.conf: Listen 8080

is it correct?

Comment: Varnish should connect to Apache instance on the same machine. Thus, In Varnish VCL ```.host``` should be ```127.0.0.1```.

Comment: Server Apache/2
Vary User-Agent
Via 1.1 varnish-v4
X-Varnish 131196   BUT Apache is functioning normally :)/

Comment: Upvote the answer if it works for you.

Comment: How can I solve this problem? :  Apache is functioning normally 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is that problem? = Having things work? :D

Comment: But I cant see my website :) Just white page...